# Using the method of undetermined coefficients, find the general solution of the differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''-3y'+2y=te^t$ is the equation I need to work on. I have gotten the roots 2,1 using the quadratic formula. The homogenous solution would be $Y_c = c_1e^{2t} + c_2e^{t}$. I then let $y =Ae^{t}$ because $g(t)=2e^{t}$, plug in $Y$ to get $(Ae^{t})''-3(Ae^{t})'+2(Ae^{t})=te^{t}$ I am stuck after this, I believe I just have to derive and solve for $Y$ somehow.

Comment: Assume that $y(t)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n t^n$ is a solution and find a recurrence relation on $a_n$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''-3y'+2y=te^t$$
$$\implies y_h=c_1e^t+c_2e^{2t}$$
For the particular solution, your guess should be:
$$y_p=t(At+B)e^t$$